# Firefox PDF plugin to view PDF in browser on Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, pdf, browser-addons

Is there any plugin or extension so I can view any PDF directly within Firefox 3.5 on Windows just like with Safari on a Mac?
It's annoying to always download and open the file.

So I'd like to be able to view the PDF just like a web page within the browser.

Comment: I'm doing that all the time without plug-in. Which version of Firefox do you use?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5. I've updated the question with the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Adobe and Foxit offer a web browser plugin.  There are also plain viewer addons like [PDFVue](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10965), but that one didn't rate particularly well.

Comment: Oh I have the free Foxit Reader installed. Does it also have the browser plugin? Or how do I get it? I haven't found anything on their website.

Comment: I've read that the latest version – 3.0 – should come with an installer that can detect your web browser.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed Adobe Reader. If you go to Firefox -> Options -> Applications you can select that PDFs should be shown within Firefox. Have a look, if your PDF reader is plugged-in there, too.

Answer (score 2):

Foxit reader is a really nice PDF reader and has a great working [Firefox plugin](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/addons.htm)

Comment: Install Foxit and it automatically opens all pdfs...

Answer (score 2):

Just another thought here. Firefox 17, which should launch on November 19 will have an inline pdf viewer. Therefore, you could download Firefox Beta if you don't want to wait. This allows you to have a pdf viewer without any extensions.

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/

Obviously, this only applies to people who can and want to update their browser.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PDF Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/636) but I can't say that it's like viewing PDFs on Safari for the Mac.

(As an aside, here's [my favorite PDF plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7518) for Firefox on the Mac.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.docu-track.com/home/prod_user/PDF-XChange_Tools/pdfx_viewer)** from Tracker Software, and really love it. First, it's free, and it has almost all the functionality you want from a pdf viewer and a pdf EDITOR. Of course, it also has browser plugins for both Firefox and IE.

Comment: simply the finest ... +1

Answer (score 1):

There's also a plugin avalaible from the [MuPDF-Project](http://ccxvii.net/mupdf/).

Comment: ...which currently doesnt work as a plugin... but MuPDF is **very** fast and **very** lightweight as a standalone viewer.

Comment: @pipitas: I foyu want a lightweight viewer, use SumatraPDF, it utilzies MuPDF but has everything you need.

Comment: The point of my comment was: you are recommending something to work as a plugin, which it doesnt.... Also, I'm **very** familiar with SumatraPDF as well. (Oh, and how do you know it has *"everything I need"*?!??)

Comment: @pipitas: Now I see what you mean...well, back then (Oct '09) the website stated something different, though it does work for me on 3.6.8, so I'm not sure what they mean with 'newer'. Also, as a Viewer it has everything I can imagine what might be needed.

Comment: 1 example of something **I** also need in a viewer, sometimes: being able to print from it, directly.

Answer (score 0):

## The popular

The most well-known free PDF readers, which both offer a browser plug-in, are [Adobe Reader](//adobe.com/reader) and [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/).

## The open source

The open-source [Sumatra PDF reader](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) is another alternative. Note: you'll have to [enable the installation of the plug-in](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/manual.html#manual-browser-plugin) during the setup.

## The plugin-free add-on

For newer versions of Firefox, an add-on which doesn't require the installation of plug-ins is also available. It's called [PDF Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) and is based upon the [PDF.JS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) project.

It is currently available for Firefox for *Android 11.0 - 16.0a1*, *Firefox 10.0 and later* and *SeaMonkey 2.7 and later*.

**Note:** PDF plug-ins such as Adobe Reader can conflict with the add-on. You'll have to disable these via *Ctrl + Shift + A* > *Plug-ins*.